# Project has become so complex and big that I am lost

Tags: programming-practices, project-management, project-structure, android-development

[image: project android]

Hello this has never happened with me before . I am making an online shopping android app which has become huge and complex . While developing the code I have followed all the clean naming conventions and made appropriate packages with proper suitable meaningful names . But still I find that this project has become so huge and complex that I am not able to work on it anymore . Any ways to simplify things here =D . What shall be done so that this code doesnt look like a Matrix to me =D

Comment: Are You under pressure to deliver a version soon?

Comment: there's no pressure at all, but I am unable to continue this ..

Comment: You should be lucky there's no time pressure :-) Still, do you do this for a paying customer, or is it all your own freedom?

Comment: its not for a customer(not getting paid for this) . But its important .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you apparently failed to do is what any large project needs: project management, documentation, planning, etc. etc.
Yes, it's paperwork, it's not fun like coding, but it needs to be done.
Make sub projects, modules, split things up according to functionality, define interfaces between those sub projects, document everything, have some diagrams (UML anyone?), things like that.

That's the only way any large project remains on track, and people know what it actually does...

Comment: I am gonna try UML out the things , thanks for the input though .

Comment: @user139848 I would go with sub projects first. Documentation easily becomes stale.